# Validating a Radio Box

Tags: c#

I'm simply trying to check that one of the three radio boxes has been checked, for some reason even when in debug console all boxes '.Selected = false' it is still skipping over my error message. Any help is appreciated.

```
 if ((rdoIndoor.Checked = false ) && ( rdoOut.Checked = false ) && ( rdoSwimming.Checked = false ))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an event style");

        }
```

Comment: I think simple syntax error. Replace '=' with '=='

Comment: Your using assignment operator is one thing, but you could also do (!rdoIndoor.Checked) instead of == false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an assignment operator instead of a comparison operator. The `=` operator is for assignment. Use `==` for comparison.

Better yet, get rid of your `==` operator altogether, and use the `!` operator, like this:

```
if ( !rdoIndoor.Checked && !rdoOut.Checked && !rdoSwimming.Checked )
{
    MessageBox.Show( "Please select an event style" );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The equality operator, used to compare values, is `==` 
So your code should be:

```
if ((rdoIndoor.Checked == false ) && 
    ( rdoOut.Checked == false ) && 
    ( rdoSwimming.Checked == false )) 
......
```

Answer (score 1):

use double equals signs `(rdoIndoor.Checked **==** false)` etc
Single '=' means assignment, i. e. from now let 'rdoIndoor.Checked' be false.
Double '==' is logical test.
You probably know that ;)

Comment: I sure did, would have taken me longer than you lot to figure it out though.